# Select from two tables return nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables, one is rooms list, and the other is users access to the rooms

rooms

```
id  name
---------
1   rm101
2   rm102
3   rm103
4   rm104
```

etc

room_access

```
rid  uid blg ben
--------------
1    1   1    1
2    1   0    1
...
```

now i need to select all rooms from rooms and join room access, but each room which a particular user e.g with uid =1 should be returned alone with rooms access data, along with the data not found in the room access, in this case room 3 and 4

the out put would be

```
rid  uid blg ben
--------------
1    1   1    1
2    1   0    1
3    1   0    0
4    1   0    0
```

this is what i tried

```
SELECT r . * , ra.blg, ra.ben, ra.uid 
FROM rooms r 
LEFT JOIN room_access ra ON r.id = ra.rid WHERE ra.uid =1
```

It only returns the two rows in the room_access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT r . * , ra.blg, ra.ben, ra.uid 
FROM rooms r 
LEFT JOIN
    room_access ra
ON
    r.id = ra.rid 
AND 
    ra.uid =1
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample of  LEFT JOIN:

---

Table >> Persons:
FirstName
LastName

---

Table >> Orders:
OrderNo

---

```
SELECT Persons.LastName, Persons.FirstName, Orders.OrderNo
FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Persons.P_Id=Orders.P_Id
ORDER BY Persons.LastName
```

Check For LEFT or RIGHT JOIN...

I'm sorry . i astounding to trace it... :|